# Cross product function in matlab

Tags: matlab, geometry, cube

Can someone explain to me how to use the cross product function in matlab?

An example, I have the following image with 6 fixed points on the cube, how to find the two other points of the cube?
[alt text http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/6479/drawcube01.png](http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/6479/drawcube01.png)

Comment: you mean you have 3d-coordinates of the fixed points?

Comment: I don't see the necessity of using cross product here. Vector addition/substraction should be enough.

Comment: Hi Antony, you can get the points using getpts function, those are in 2D, you have to make them become 3D by adding one more dimension(value 1).

Comment: @Anthony - The cross-product of the two vectors gives him the third point that's unknown.  Vector addition/subtraction is not sufficient.

Comment: I'm still confused... if all 6 points are chosen in 2D, they will all lie in the same plane and the cross product of any pair will just give you a vector normal to the plane of the image. How do you assign a third dimension to each point?

Comment: im=imread('drawcube_01.jpg');
imshow(im);
hold on;
[x y]=getpts;
plot(x,y,'or');
a=[x(1) y(1) 1]';
b=[x(2) y(2) 1]';
f=[x(3) y(3) 1]';
h=[x(4) y(4) 1]';
g=[x(5) y(5) 1]';
c=[x(6) y(6) 1]';

Comment: The six points are the corners of the cube.  What does "chosen in 2D" mean?  The plane of interest is the one that contains the three corners in red.  The normal vector is perpendicular to that plane and points towards the corner of interest.

Comment: @duffymo: Based on the comment by Hoang, it is clear he is plotting the image above and simply choosing 6 points by mouse click (which gives `x` and `y` values for each point). He then chooses a z value of 1 for all of them, so any vector between them will lie in the x-y plane, and any cross product will lie parallel to the z-axis.

Comment: what is the task? to get 2d or 3d coordinates? If it is 2D, I can get 2d coordinates of the missing corners by addition/substraction (as I said before). If 3D, then assigning z=1 to all 6 points is definitely wrong. Never can any six corners of a cube lie in one plane.

Comment: I have the solution like this, vab=cross(cross(a,b),cross(h,g));
vac=cross(cross(a,c),cross(f,h));
vae=cross(cross(b,f),cross(c,g));

vab=vab/vab(3);
vac=vac/vac(3);
vae=vae/vae(3);
d=cross(cross(b,vac),cross(c,vab));
d=d/d(3);
e=cross(cross(g,vac),cross(f,vab));
e=e/e(3);
Can someone explain to me how do the two points d & e are generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good to know what the cross-product function means without using Matlab.

If you have two vectors **A** = ax **i** + ay **j** + az **k** and **B** = bx **i** + by **j** + bz **k**, the cross product is defined as the vector C as follows:

**C** = (ay*bz - by*az) **i** - (ax*bz - bx*az) **j** + (ax*by - bx*ay) **k**

You can visualize **C** as perpendicular to both **A** and **B** in the direction of a right-hand screw when you rotate **A** into **B**.

Another way to write it is:

**C** = ab sin(θ)**n**, where a is the magnitude of **A**, b is the magnitude of **B**, and n is the unit normal vector.

In your case, the magnitudes of A and B are the lengths of the sides of the Rubik's Cube.  The point that you want is the end of the vector **C**.

ADDITIONAL DETAIL:

In your case, the vector **A** runs from the bottom point to the corner on the right; the vector **B** starts at that common bottom point to the corner on the left.  Cross **A** into **B** to get the vector that runs perpendicular to the bottom plane up towards the unknown corner point.  Make it a unit vector.  Multiply the unit vector by the length of the side of the cube.  Add the common bottom point to the components of this vector and you have the absolute coordinates of the unknown corner.  Repeat for the other three points and you're done.

Comment: Hi duffymo, could you give me some codes with explanation, I have read enough on wiki :-s To solve it is a problem, I have not immagined how do I get the results, Thank you.

Comment: Amend your question with details showing how you'd do it and I'll see if I can help.  I'm not the homework bitch.

Comment: oops, thanks for your suggestion, I put another tag to my question :D